# Creating posts linked to map

Tags: 7, google-maps, javascript, location

I want to create a map where on clicking on a certain location ,a user can find all the content/nodes/posts related to that location. ( Something like http://42floors.com/ )

Is it possible to build it using drupal? Can you suggest some modules that will be useful for this purpose?
Thanks. :)

Comment: Whar's wrong with the question?

Comment: I haven't voted, but I think it's 1) The question is only relevant to others who want to copy the exact same site, thus it's to localized. You should define the functionality you want, and ask multiple specific questions about that. And 2) Your question isn't self contained, by linking to an external site, the relevant answer to the question will change with site that you link to. Solving this ties in with 1).

Comment: Accept rate should never be a reason for downvoting.  Also, if you look at the questions with unaccepted answers, you will see that several don't work for the particular situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[location](http://drupal.org/project/location)

[gmap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap)

[views](http://drupal.org/project/views)

With these three drupal modules you can easily create a map which will display all nodes with location details.

Comment: What has been your experience with http://drupal.org/project/getlocations ?

Comment: I didnt used it yest, but seems like its an alternate to gmap .. Gmap stable module uses old api, but this one uses latest api 3

Comment: I did some research, and I think you better use http://drupal.org/project/getlocations :)